# Math operations with multiple dataframes having different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following two pandas dataframes:

```
dt1 = {'date':['2020-05-18', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-20', '2020-05-21'], 'X1':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'X2':[23, 45, 16, 8]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dt1)
```

and

```
dt2 = {'date':['2020-04-18', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-22'], 'X1':[20, 19, 18], 'X2':[23, 16, 8]} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dt2)
```

I would like to get the difference for each column based on the corresponding date. For the dataframes above, the expected output is:

```
dt3 = {'date':['2020-05-19'], 'X1':[2], 'X2':[29]} 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dt3)
```

Obviously, my dataframes are substantially bigger, but the idea is the same. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df3=(df1.set_index('date')-df2.set_index('date')).dropna().reset_index()
         date   X1    X2
0  2020-05-19  2.0  29.0
```